# Enable mod_http_fileserver ejabberd 17.03 windows

Tags: windows, xmpp, ejabberd

I currently have an ejabberd 17.03 server running on a windows machine.
I am trying to enable mod_http_fileserver on ejabberd. I used the following configuration in the listen section :

```
port: 5280
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/api": mod_http_api
  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
web_admin: true
http_bind: true
## register: true
captcha: false
```

and in the modules :

```
mod_http_fileserver:
docroot: "C:\\Tech\\ejabberd-17.03\\www"
accesslog: "C:\\Tech\\ejabberd-17.03\\logs\\access.log"
directory_indices:
  - "index.html"
  - "main.htm"
custom_headers:
  "X-Powered-By": "Erlang/OTP"
  "X-Fry": "It's a widely-believed fact!"
content_types:
  ".ogg": "audio/ogg"
  ".png": "image/png"
  ".jpg": undefined
default_content_type: "text/html"
```

However, when I try to access http://localhost:5280/pub/archive, I get a 404 not found response.

Can someone help me out please ?
Thanks !

Comment: Is indentation of ejabberd.yml correct? Do you have any errors in ejabberd.log?

Comment: Yeah my identation is correct and I don't have any error. I realized that I am able to open the page http://localhost:5280/pub/archive/ in Mozilla Firefox, but not in Chrome. In Chrome I am getting the following error : "The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again." Any ideas ?